# SQL Server Entity-Relationship Model generation

Tags: sql-server-2005, diagram

What's the best tool to reverse engineer an SQL Server 2005 to an entity-relationship Model diagram? Could it be done usin SSMS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need more than the Database Diagram functionality provided in each database in SSMS? This will generate a diagram with any tables you choose and any relationships that are defined.

I've also used Visio which is useful if you have a large number of tables and need more control over the diagram.

Comment: I was actually not aware of the Database Diagram, which worked fine!